# 'Duplicate entry check validation' on 'column of formula'

Tags: excel, validation, duplicates, formula

I have a column with cells built upon a formula, let say 'column J':
For each row (e.g. row 5):

```
=CONCATENATE( GetMyProp("Title"),"-",I5,"-",TEXT(G5,"000000"))
```

I have a data validation that check if a cell has the same value that another cell in the same column. For each row (e.g. row 5):

```
=COUNTIF($J$2:$J$216,J5)=1
```

The thing is that the validation doesn't seem to work since when I click "Circle Invalid Data", all my cells are circled, even if their values are different.

Comment: a) What is the nature of *GetMyProp*? It doesn't appear to be a native Excel capability. b) Is the *Data Validation* on just column J or more columns? Is 'more columns', the formula should be more like `=COUNTIF($J$2:$J$216, $J5)=1` (note the *absolute column* lock on `$J5`).

Comment: a) Yes sorry, I didn't specified what GetMyProp is:
It is a VB function to get a custom property, that I took from here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745821/how-to-show-custom-property-in-a-cell
b) The Data Validation is just on column J. Indeed the formula is working well if the column cells are simple flat numbers. But it doesn't work anymore when these numbers are generated by formulas